# translate image K2 using joomfish

Tags: joomla

In a standard Joomla+Joomfish installation, when translating an article, there is the option to upload a different image for the translation (e.g. French packaging vs. English packaging).

When translating K2 items, I do not see an option to provide a translated image to the item. Have I turned off a setting somewhere or is this standard Joomfish feature not available when working with K2?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a possible solution. Maybe it's quite a trick, but it works.

Since K2 doesn't store the path to the image into the database, I've used other fields that are stored. In particular, I've used the image_credits field.

In that field I insert the path to the image (/images/myimage.jpg) that I've uploaded on the server via ftp or via any other means that allow you to upload a picture into the image folder.

Now I've made some minor modifications into the template overrides of the item, adding an else branch to the if that manage the image

```
<?php else: 
if(!empty($this->item->image_credits)): ?>
    <figure class="itemImageBlock">
<a class="itemImage modal" rel="{handler: 'image'}" href="<?php echo $this->item->image_credits; ?>" title="<?php echo JText::_('K2_CLICK_TO_PREVIEW_IMAGE'); ?>"> 
    <img src="<?php echo $this->item->image_credits; ?>" alt="<?php if(!empty($this->item->image_caption)) echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($this->item->image_caption); else echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($this->item->title); ?>" style="width:100%; height:auto;" />
</a>
    </figure>
<?php endif; ?>
```

That's it. Now I can "translate" the image using Joomfish